# attempting to create new rails application with railties error - is there a parent level Gemfile hidden somewhere?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm having trouble understanding where this Gemfile referred to by the bundle install output is. My general project directory is /code and there is no Gemfile here, hidden or visible.  I tried rvm implode to clear things out but the issue remains.

```
$ gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-4.2.5
Parsing documentation for rails-4.2.5
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

$ rails new myapp --database=postgresql
Could not find proper version of railties (4.0.2) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ rails -v
Could not find proper version of railties (4.0.2) in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 2.2.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-linux]

$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have an issue with your global gemset. Try creating a new gemset for the app using rvm:

```
rvm use 2.2-head@myapp --create
```

From there install rails and see if all goes well.

Comment: Tried that and am getting the same railties error, unfortunately